# A Common exception at Struts2 application deployment time

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, struts

I use NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 and Apache Tomcat 7.0.14.0. I built a Struts2 application with IDE and building works well, with no exceptions. But, IDE's server log gives a same exception every deployment time for all Struts2 applications. How ever the applications run well with no other exceptions.

Here is the exception:

```
    Jul 6, 2012 9:40:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/OnlineBooking] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP] with root cause
    java.io.UTFDataFormatException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.  
at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:623)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.load(XMLEncodingDetector.java:1017)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.skipString(XMLEncodingDetector.java:968)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.scanXMLDecl(XMLEncodingDetector.java:1224)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.getEncoding(XMLEncodingDetector.java:124)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.getEncoding(XMLEncodingDetector.java:112)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.determineSyntaxAndEncoding(ParserController.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:190)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:119)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:192)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

How can I avoid this? where does the problem exist?

Comment: Looks like you have a XML parser in you library and it is conflicting with others. Try to change it with the newer version or remove it. Seems that problem with some jasper jars.

Comment: @batbaatar, Thanks. I use struts2, 2.2.3 version.It might has new or best supporting XML parsing libraries. I d better use another newest struts2 library 2.2.4.  But 2.2.3 must be supporting well..

Answer (score 0):

```
java.io.UTFDataFormatException    xmlparser
```

I guess the problem is the xml file.

Is it copied from other file? May be the encoding is different, you should type it by yourself. Try adding the following to your xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

By the way,I'm a Chinese student and I'm not good at English,sorry.

Comment: I tried adding that line. but still it is there. Thanks for your attention. Chinese people are v good at all languages, don't lie. :)